# how to map samba server drive to some local drive in C# using net use?

Tags: c#, samba

how to map samba server drive to some local drive in C# using net use ?
And how to display them in Windows explorer like window ?

Any code snippet is highly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Any body can help me on this ? pls...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend creating a batch file which contains the command you want to execute and then call this batch file from your C# application. This ensures if you need to change the **net use** command it is well encapsulated.

**myBatchFile.cmd**

```
net use z: \\server\resource
```

**Application code**

```
Process.Start(@"C:\myBatchFile.cmd");
```

You will need to add this using to your application.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) for more information on Process.Start:

Can you expand on "And how to display them in Windows explorer like window ?"